# Graph of $\quad\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}$.

Tags: rational-functions

I was using google graphs to find the graph of $$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}$$ and it gave me:

[image: img]

Why is $x=2$ defined as $3$? I know that it is supposed to tend to 3. But where is the asymptote???

Comment: That's not a "dot" at $x=2$: it's a "hole".  In a rational function, when there is a common factor $(x - a)$ in the numerator and denominator, it "cancels", but only in the sense that the function remains _undefined_ at $x = a$, but a finite limit for the function will exist as $x$ approaches $a$.  Vertical asymptotes will occur at the values of $x$ at which the _limit_ doesn't exist.

Comment: Most of what you said makes sense, but that is not a hole. Google graphs has this feature where where can "trace". That dot is the tracing ball.

Comment: Nevertheless, that _is_ an undefined point.  I don't know what sort of representation Google uses for that.

Comment: Have a look : [Click Me!](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=(x%5E3-8)%2Fx%5E2-4#sclient=psy-ab&q=(x%5E3-8)%2F(x%5E2-4)&oq=(x%5E3-8)%2F(x%5E2-4)&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0i5i30j0i8i30l2.8962.10944.0.11800.2.2.0.0.0.0.132.260.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.COafjoV73Qw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk&fp=3c6a4ab992f03a51&biw=1680&bih=925)

Comment: Well, it is regrettable that Google's plotter has such a deficiency...  This shows once again that one shouldn't rely on computers _too_ much on mathematical matters: one need to have some awareness oneself about special situations.

Comment: I think my real regret is that **Google**'s plotter has such a deficiency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is a **removable singularity** at $x = 2$, *there will be no asymptote*.

You're correct that the function is not defined at $x = 2$. Consider the point $(2, 3)$ to be a hole in the graph.

Note that in the numerator, $$(x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 4) = x^3 - 8,$$ and in the denominator $$(x-2)(x+ 2) = x^2 - 4$$

When we simplify by canceling (while recognizing $x\neq 2$), we end with the rational function $$\frac{x^2 + 2x + 4}{x+2}$$

We can confirm that the "hole" at $x = 2$ is a removable singularity by confirming that its limit exists: $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2 + 2x + 4}{x+2} = 3$$

In contrast, however, we do see, that there is an asymptote at $x = -2$. We can know this without graphing by evaluating the limit of the function as $x$ approaches $-2$ from the left and from the right:

$$\lim_{x \to -2^-} \frac{x^2 + 2x + 4}{x+2} \to -\infty$$

$$\lim_{x \to -2^+} \frac{x^2 + 2x + 4}{x+2} \to +\infty$$

Hence, there exists a vertical asymptote at $x = -2$.

Comment: Thanks, Hele. Glad to help!

Comment: For my dear tutor here. +1

Comment: Hello, @Babak! did you sleep well?

Comment: Yes @amWhy. It was deep and dreamy and empty of any Maths. :-)

Comment: @Babak we need that every once and awhile; a respite from math, be it only temporary, but to be savored!

Comment: @amWhy: Exactly! I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no asymptote at $x=2$. Note that 
$$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4}=\frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}{(x-2)(x+2)}.$$ 
For $x\ne 2$, we can cancel the $x-2$.

So *near* $x=2$ our function is very well behaved, it has a nice limit.  The singularity at $2$ is called a *removable singularity*. If we define a new function $g(x)$ by $g(x)$ equal to our given expression when $x\ne 2$, and $g(2)= 3$, the function $g(x)$ is very nice everywhere except at $x=-2$. (The singularity at $x=-2$ is not removable.)

Many pieces of graphing software completely ignore removable singularities. At least Alpha had the decency to put a dot there.

Comment: Some of the older graphing calculators which had lower resolution used to leave a "gap" (no "pixel" darkened) on the display for the function.

Comment: Nope, my TI-84 does'nt show anything.

Comment: Pity, because it really ought to.  Some resident graphing software on personal computers doesn't show anything either, but will indicate a problem with the point when you place the cursor there (if it is permitted to do so accurately enough) by declaring there is no defined value there -- some even make an audible "click"!

Answer (score 1):

There will only be an asymptote if the limit is infinity. in your case, for all points $x\neq 2$:
$$\frac{x^3-8}{x^2-4} = \frac{x^2+2x+4}{x+2} $$
Which has no discontinuities!